# Passing data around Phonegap pages using object and localStorage

Tags: android, jquery, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I need to pass some data around two pages.
Here is a sample of the code I use for this:

```
myContentObject = {

    content: new Array(),

    import: function(dados){
        this.Content = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("myContentObject.content"));
        return this;
    },

    export: function(){
        window.localStorage.setItem("myContentObject.content", JSON.stringify(this.content));
        return this;
    },
}
```

The object is initialized during the JS execution, the import function is called on the 'pageinit' event, and the export function is called when the user clicks the navigation buttons.

The functions do fire, you can put alerts in them and see them pop up. However, the data does not persist.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

`localStorage` keys can't contain `.`